# How to loop through an array of objects, dictionary and output data to a table using Jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

With a payload of this format:

```
payload = (
 ('Franky hansen', '6 ',  '9', '12', 'prospekt'),
 ('Timmy hansen', '6 ',  '9', '12', 'not_interested'),
 ('Jhon hansen', '0 ',  '0', '0', 'Inactive')
     )
```

In the .Html file with the table to output to I write following jinja code:

```html
<table class="table table-striped ">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for header in heads %}
         <th scope="col">{{ header.name }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for deal in payload %}
      <tr>
         {% for data in deal %}
         <th scope="row">{{ data }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I get the right output to table:

[image]

But how do I loop and get the right data to right place if the payload is in this format:

```
payload = 
 [
   {'name': 'Tom hansen'}, {'avg': '5 '}, {'num': '8'}, {'won': '11'},
   {'stat': 'customer'},
 
   {'name': 'Franky hansen'}, {'avg': '6 '}, {'num': '9'}, {'won': '12'},
   {'stat': 'prospekt'},
 
   {'name': 'Timmy hansen'}, {'avg': '7 '}, {'num': '10'}, {'won': '13'},
   {'stat': 'inactive'}
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just "How to iterate through a dictionary". Here is how to do it.

```html
<table class="table table-striped ">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for header in heads %}
         <th scope="col">{{ header.name }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for deal in payload %}
      <tr>
         {% for key,data in deal.items() %}
         <th scope="row">{{ data }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

OR

```html
<table class="table table-striped ">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for header in heads %}
         <th scope="col">{{ header.name }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for deal in payload %}
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{ deal.get('name') }}</th>
         <th scope="row">{{ deal.get('avg') }}</th>
         <th scope="row">{{ deal.get('num') }}</th>
         <th scope="row">{{ deal.get('won') }}</th>
         <th scope="row">{{ deal.get('stat') }}</th>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is a dictonary?

Comment: @RossoTheMan Read [this](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) one

Comment: It gave me strange result. Only one value in each row and rest is replaced with 'none'. And it did a whole table of this 3 times.